# External HD won't mount, is my partition table ok?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mount

When I plug in my external HD it's not mounting automatically anymore (sometimes, only the FAT-32 partition does up—but not the HFS+ one).

I've tried mounting it using the command line but without success (both in readonly and by ignoring the journaling).

Here is some info on the disk layout:

```
$ sudo gpt -vvv -r show disk2
gpt show: disk2: mediasize=1000204886016; sectorsize=512; blocks=1953525168
gpt show: disk2: MBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk2: MBR part: type=175, start=2, size=976762584
gpt show: disk2: MBR part: type=11, start=976762587, size=976762581
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1           1
           2   976762584      1  MBR part 175
   976762586           1
   976762587   976762581      2  MBR part 11


$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk2
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 121601/255/63 [1953525168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
        Starting       Ending
#: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         2 -  976762584] HFS+
2: 0B 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 976762587 -  976762581] Win95 FAT-32
3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused


$ diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         500.1 GB   disk2s1
   2:                 DOS_FAT_32 TRUC & CIE              500.1 GB   disk2s2
```

Is anything wrong with the partition table? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the Disk Utility app  to repair it?

Comment: @HackSaw Yes, it fails with error 69845. One article advised to do a `fsck -fy` but as I can't mount the drive I can't do it...

Comment: You don't need to mount a disk to run fsck, in fact you generally don't want them mounted during a repair run.

Comment: How did you end up with an MBR-only partition table on a drive with an HFS volume? Macs like GPT much better than MBR. Hybrid partition tables, which are basically GPT with a legacy or fake MBR in the first block, work too. But it looks like you have a pure MBR with an HFS partition in it, which is sketchy.

Comment: Not really, external disks often come with MBR style tables, and there isn't a lot of reason to change that on an external. Other partition tables are less dumb, but you don't really need a smart one for an external.

Comment: @HackSaw @Spiff It's actually a friend's drive (really :)) so I don't know what he did with it... We already tried fsck -fy in single user mode but it didn't change anything. I was pretty sure it only ran on the SSD, not the external drive. I just ran `fsck_hfs -fdy /dev/disk2s1` and it returned "CheckHFS returned -1317"...

Comment: Did the debug output mention anything about invalid Btree node sizes? You might be able to fix that with fsck -fRy. Beyond that, you might try a volume recovery tool of some kind.

Comment: @HackSaw I don't think it did. All I see is "Incorrect number of thread records" or "Incorrect number of file hard links". I still ran the command but nothing new.